# Minishift MySQL service not showing actual database

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift

Using Springboot 2.2.4 and a local distribution of Openshift (Minishift, Kubernetes Master 1.11, Openshift Web Console 3.11).

The app itself is just a *spring-boot-starter-data-rest* CRUD for a simple Employee entity configured in a pod within Openshift. The data source is a MySQL service in another container.

On deployment some data is loaded in the employee table. Just 4 employees for testing purposes.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

--
-- Data for table `employee`
--

INSERT INTO employee VALUES
(1,'Leslie','Andrews','leslie@luv2code.com'),
(2,'Emma','Baumgarten','emma@luv2code.com'),
(3,'Avani','Gupta','avani@luv2code.com'),
(4,'Yuri','Petrov','yuri@luv2code.com');
```

Everything works perfect. All of the endpoints are well published and all works perfectly.

But just out for curiosity, I am trying to connect some mysql viewer to check the data that it is loaded on startup and changed later on API usage. But I can't find the table anywhere. I am trying two ways:

- Entering the mysql container and going through command line (mysql command). I connect to the database, but it is empty (no tables).
- Configuring a third pod with a phpMysqlAdmin instance, which apparently connects too to the database perfectly but, again, showing no tables or data (other than information_schema).

[image]

configmap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-bootstrap
data:
  application.properties: |-
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mydatabase:3306/mydatabase
```

fabric8\deployment.yml

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: mysql
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mydatabase
              key: database-user
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mydatabase
              key: database-password
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can't easily run databases in a container. Imagine there are 3 instances of your DB in your cluster, A, B, and C (each on a different node). Now, imagine that your load-balancer chooses instance-A to run your SQL initialisation against, and by luck, your app is routed to the same container. Now, when you bring up your viewer (or 2nd consumer container) the load-balancer connects you to a different instance on a different node, say instance-B. You can search as hard as you like in instance B, but you'll not find tables that only exist in instance-A.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres have the same behaver.

Entering the Postgres container and going through command line (Postgres command). I connect to the database, but it is empty (no tables).

I use minishift.

jdbc:postgresql://localhost:25432/pstgrs1 work in client. I used spring app, it works, but table is empty.

Example
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;
CREATE TABLE cities(id serial PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), population integer);